# Как сделать подобный прогресс-бар с деление на три секции с разными цветами?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет

Нужно сделать такой прогресс-бар

Вот так должен выглядеть : [клик](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgg9jm8k52lddld/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-05-22%2012.54.18.png?dl=0)

Очень важно, что бы секции бились на разные цвета.

Перепробовал уже все плагины, а там или svg, или canvas и нет возможности разбить на цвета.

Спасибо за советы

Comment: инлайн svg + css как вариант, тогда можно менять цвета динамически. Но я не очень понял что значит "разбить на цвета"

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Ну, у меня есть три разные секции. Каждая из них должна иметь свой цвет на любом этапе. В плагинах, которые я смотрел можно закрасить только весь путь, а не конкретные его части

Comment: На картинке я вижу окружность, состоящую из трёх цветов, как она связана с прогресс-баром? Какое у нее интерактивное проведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код из *.html, откроешь как страницу, с которой можно стянуть сам `<svg>...</svg>`
Меняй долевые значения переменных в последней строке

```
<svg id="circle_svg" width="30" height="30"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function circle(svgId, v1, v2, v3) {
        var svg = d3.select("#" + svgId),
            width = +svg.attr("width"),
            height = +svg.attr("height"),
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
            g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["lime", "red" ,"blue"]);
        var data = [v1, v2, v3];

        var pie = d3.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function (d) {
                return d;
            });

        var path = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(radius - 4);

        var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        arc.append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.value);
            });
    }

    circle('circle_svg', 3, 5, 4);
</script>
```

Comment: как для такого круга тянуть целую d3.js шутишь? :DD

Comment: вдруг в проекте и не такие звери )

Comment: Извини за долгий ответ! Спасибо, вроде то, что нужно!